# How do I go about changing the Management certificates for my Azure subscribtion?

Tags: azure, certificate

I need to change the Management certificates for my Azure subscription, can I just delete the old one and upload a new one? How do I assign the new cert as the management cert?

Comment: All the certificates can be uses as management certificates, so assigning one is not necessary.  If you download your "publishsettings" file you can use that to register different apps as @Igorek mentioned, like powershell, VS and others.

Answer (score 3):

You can upload as many as <del>`10`</del> `25` certs per subscription.

If you delete old certificates, any applications that use those certificates will no longer be able to manage your Azure subscriptions until they've been switch to newly updated certificates.

Apps that typically use management certificates are:
Visual Studio, deployment scripts, Cerebrata/RedGate Management tools, AzureWatch, WASABi, etc.